# When does order matter in redirection?

Tags: bash, zsh, io-redirection, mksh

I've written a script that has a few log outs with `printf "..." 1>&2` inside a function. Running that script (build.sh) and I've noticed that if I want to redirect stderr to stdout and stdout to a file[0], success is dependent on order:

- `./build.sh 2> /tmp/log.txt` works (obviously)
- `./build.sh 1>/tmp/log.txt 2>&1` works
- `./build.sh 2>&1 1>/tmp/log.txt` doesn't redirect to the file

And with `echo`:

- `echo "test" 2>&1 >/tmp/log.txt` works
- `echo "test" >/tmp/log.txt 2>&1` works

This was replicated in bash, zsh, and originally reported in mksh.

When does the order of redirection statements in the command matter? Thanks!

0: Not sure *why* I'd do this, but a user of the script tried it and got confused when the redirection failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order is important because the redirections are executed in the order they are listed from left to right.
In your second example (correct) `./build.sh 1>/tmp/log.txt 2>&1` it first maps fd "1" to a file and then duplicates "1" as "2" and with this mapping executes the build script.
In the 3rd example (not working) it first duplicates the **current** "1" as "2" and only after that maps "1" to a file. The current "1" was not the file at the time of duplication. It was your terminal or the CI shell script output grabber.